# Can I call operations on Entities within an Aggregate Root?

Tags: domain-driven-design

As per the title, I have the following classes:

```
public class Company : AggregateRoot {
    public AddressBook AddressBook { get; set; }
}

public class AddressBook {
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public Address GetPrimaryAddress() {
        return Addresses.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Is it acceptable for me to call:

```
company.AddressBook.GetPrimaryAddress();
```

Or should I expose a `GetPrimaryAddress()` method on `Company` that in turn calls the `AddressBook` method?

I know I shouldn't have **references** to entities within an AggregateRoot but I wasn't sure what the rulings are on calling operations.

#### Update

For what it's worth, below is a diagram (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpcHX.png) for full size) of my *actual* model. `ContactList` contains rules for how all types of contact (Person/Business Location) should be managed, such as what happens when a primary contact is removed. It also works around some caveats of how RavenDB stores nested entities (essentially we need to provide our own Id strategy - hence the LastContactId property).

[image: Client Model]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's all depending on the context and I assume that Company really is the AR for that specific context. The same Company can be a simple object in other contexts. Now, I'm not a fan of dogmatic use of rules and patterns so it is not important what the 'rule' says.

In this case I won't expose the Address as it seems to be an internal of the Company. As a coosnumer of the Company, I want its primary address, I don't care you're using the AddresBook to organize them.

To give a not so common example: the AR Human has two Eye objects. Will you ask the Person to give one of his eyes so you can check their color or you ask the Person directly what color his eyes are?

Comment: that was a good analogy. Whilst I am still calling some operations on the address book directly (mainly for adding/removing items from the address book), I've moved operations that represent core domain concepts (such as PrimaryContact, HeadOffice) onto the Company aggregate

Comment: Be aware that the context matters. For some actions the Company is the AR, in others the AddressBook is the AR.

Answer (score 1):

According to the *Aggregate* pattern:

> Transient references to the internal members can be passed out for use within a single operation only.

Meaning - a Company can pass a reference to its Address object to other objects outside the aggregate, but Address cannot be a member of any other object outside the aggregate.

For example, an object User can ask a reference to an Address from a Company, but User cannot have Address as one of its members.

And why is that so important?

> Because the root controls access, it cannot be blindsided by changes to the internals.

If an object User would have Address as one of its members, it might pull it out of the database without its Company and thus, Company would be blindsided by changes to its internals.

Please see a [post](http://itziksaban.blogspot.com/2012/03/aggregate-ddd-boosting-performance.html) I've wrote in which i demonstrate why is this principle so important.

Comment: The `AddressBook` can never be obtained directly, nor can it be replaced (in my actual model), one must always go via the Company. If it is okay to pass references to objects outside the Aggregate, does this transcend to operations - i.e. can I call operations on those instances from outside the aggregate?

Comment: If it is a query operation - it dosen't matter anyway - the root is not blindsided since there are no changes. if it is a command operation - you can still do that as long as you make sure the root is aware for any changes caused by this command. it can be done via event or something.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, this is one of the things I've always found hard to get right in DDD - do you always access entities through their aggregate root and probably violate the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) at some point (AggregateRoot.EntityX.EntityY.DoStuff()) ? Do you short-circuit the aggregate root ? Do you add at the aggregate root level one direct accessor for each sub-sub-entity you want to access, muddling the aggregate root ?

One way to solve that could be : try to make every object talk only to its immediate or nearby neighbors and not to some distant stranger. Use multiple objects that each know a small part of the path from the aggregate root to the final entity you want to access.

- The first object knows only the aggregate root,
- It injects AggregateRoot.SubEntity1 into a second object,
- Second object in turn injects SubEntity1.SubEntity2 into a third object
- and so on.

Interestingly enough, one thing this reveals is the (ir)relevance of some of your domain entities. In the Address example, ask yourself if it feels right for every object that wants to access the primary Address of a Company to be injected an AddressBook. If it seems too convoluted, maybe you should not have an AddressBook in the first place. Maybe it isn't such a strong notion that it deserves to be part of the ubiquitous language after all.

Or, maybe you'll find out an AddressBook is precisely the right object to be used by your client object, and that this client object tries to do too many things at a time in manipulating both a Company and an Address.

Comment: to begin with I just had a simple `List<Address>` property on the `Company` and was handling the add/remove/update operations via the Aggregate. However, I then needed to add two address books (or what became contact lists). Having 10+ operations on `Company` just to manage contacts started to feel like it violated SRP, and was not a concern of the company.